# Imprimir nulo ou nao nulo na matriz no Python

Tags: python, matriz

Se a matriz tiver só zero imprima 'nulo' se não imprima 'nao nulo'
Eu fiz assim:

```
m=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
soma1=0
for novo1 in m[0]:
    soma1+=novo1
soma2=0
for novo2 in m[1]:
    soma2+=novo2
soma3=0
for novo3 in m[2]:
    soma3+=novo3

if soma1==0 and soma2==0 and soma3==0:
    print('nulo')
else:
    print('nao nulo')
```

Mas desse jeito eu tenho como que fazer manualmente.

Gostaria de saber como faço sem ser assim, mas considerando por exemplo uma matriz maior. Tipo se fosse uma matriz de 500 números não poderia fazer assim.

Comment: Porque você esta somando os valores com "0"?

Comment: nao entendi a pergunta desculpa ta falando da lista? se for é que eu estava testando aqui mas pode considerar outra lista por exemplo [[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] na saida vai dizer que nao é nulo

Comment: Deve retornar "nulo" se a matriz possuir todos os elementos igual a zero ou se a soma de todos os elementos é 0? Basicamente, [0, -1, 1] não possui todos os valores igual a zero, mas a soma será 0, neste caso qual deve ser a saída?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Resolução

Utilizando dois for, um para percorrer "m" e outro para percorrer os seus sub-itens, criei outro `array` para o itens que serão somados, mas se você for utilizar apenas somas com zero é melhor trocar o `array` e colocar o valor estático, e por fim eu criei um *flag* chamada "isNulo" assim se existir algum valor que não seja zero ela é setada para "False".

**Caso 1**

```
m=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
soma=[0,0,0]
isNulo=True
count=0

for x in m:
  for y in x:
    soma[count]+=y
    if soma[count] != 0:
      isNulo = False
  count += 1
    
if isNulo:
    print('nulo')
else:
    print('nao nulo')
```

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Imprimir-nulo-ou-nao-nulo-na-matriz-no-python/10924)

**Caso 2**

Caso seja o que o [Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) citou, "soma de todos os elementos é 0", apenas coloque o `for` fora do `for` interno

```
m=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
soma=[0,0,0]
isNulo=True
count=0

for x in m:
  for y in x:
    soma[count]+=y
  if soma[count] != 0:
    isNulo = False
  count += 1
    
if isNulo:
    print('nulo')
else:
    print('nao nulo')
```

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Imprimir-nulo-ou-nao-nulo-na-matriz-no-python-2/10925)

**Caso 3**

A mesma ideia do caso 2, mas sem a necessidade da soma com valores diferentes de zero

```
m=[[0,1,-1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
isNulo=True
count=0

for x in m:
  soma = 0
  for y in x:
    soma+=y
  if soma != 0:
    isNulo = False

if isNulo:
    print('nulo')
else:
    print('nao nulo')
```

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Imprimir-nulo-ou-nao-nulo-na-matriz-no-Python-3/10926)

Comment: muito Obrigado!

Comment: E o que aconteceria se a "matriz" tivesse mais que 2 dimensoes?

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa ficar somando os elementos, basta percorrer as listas e ir verificando se cada valor é diferente de zero.

Uma maneira de resolver é primeiro criar uma função que verifica se uma lista possui somente zeros:

```
def somente_zeros(lista):
    for elemento in lista:
        if elemento != 0:
            return False;
    return True;
```

Repare que se encontrar algum elemento que não é zero, a função já retorna `False` (não tem somente zeros), pois neste caso eu nem preciso percorrer o restante da lista.

Se o `for` terminar, significa que ninguém entrou no `if`, e portanto todos os elementos são iguais a zero, e a função retorna `True`.

Agora é só percorrer a matriz. No fundo, a matriz é apenas uma lista de listas: uma lista na qual cada elemento também é uma lista. Então basta fazer um `for` nos elementos da matriz, e usar a função acima para verificar se ele só tem zeros:

```
m = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

# para cada linha da matriz
for linha in m:
    # se encontrou algum elemento diferente de zero, já imprime a mensagem e sai do loop
    if not somente_zeros(linha):
        print('nao nulo')
        break
else:
    print('nulo')
```

O `for` percorre cada linha da matriz e passa-a para a função `somente_zeros`. Se a lista tiver algum elemento diferente de zero, entra no `if`, que já imprime a mensagem "nao nulo" e sai do loop (o `break` interrompe o `for`).

Se nenhuma das linhas entrar no `if` (ou seja, todos os elementos são iguais a zero), o `break` não é chamado e o bloco `else` é executado (sim, em Python, um `for` [pode ter um bloco `else` associado](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause)).

---

Como solução geral para "matrizes" com mais de duas dimensões (ou seja, lista de listas de listas de listas...) você pode criar outra função auxiliar para converter a matriz para uma lista de uma dimensão:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(matriz):
    result = []
    for elemento in matriz:
        # se for um elemento iterável (exceto strings), faz o flatten recursivamente
        if isinstance(elemento, Iterable) and not isinstance(elemento, str):
            result.extend(flatten(elemento))
        else:
            result.append(elemento)
    return result
```

Com isso, não importa a dimensão da matriz, ela será reduzida para uma única lista, contendo todos os elementos. Sendo assim, você só precisa percorrê-la e verificar se algum elemento não é zero:

```
m = [
    [
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    ],
    [
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    ],
    [
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    ]
]

for elemento in flatten(m):
    if elemento != 0:
        print('nao nulo')
        break
else:
    print('nulo')
```

A ideia é a mesma da função `somente_zeros`: se encontrar algum elemento que não é zero, imprime "nao nulo" e interrompe o *loop* (não precisa verificar o restante, pois já encontrei um elemento que não é zero).

Se o `for` chega ao fim, quer dizer que todos os elementos são zero. O bloco `else` é executado e imprime "nulo".

Comment: @ hkotsubo, Cool! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

> Use Numpy

Voce esta construindo o que chama de matriz através das listas do python, eu tenho minhas dúvidas se voce pode chamar isso de matriz no sentido matemático da palavra. Utilizando o numpy voce pode construir matrizes através de arrays genuinos e fazer varias operações especificas para matrizes. Resolvendo sua questão:

```
import numpy as np
m1 = np.array([np.zeros(100),np.zeros(100)])
m2 = m1.copy()
m2[0][10]=1

# Testando m1
print("Nulo") if m1.sum()==0 else print("Não Nulo")
Nulo

# Testando m2
print("Nulo") if m2.sum()==0 else print("Não Nulo")
Não Nulo
```

> Editada

Com numpy voc pode tambem contar o zeros em uma matriz com apenas um comando, então poderiamos fazer assim tb:

```
m1 = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
print('Nulo') if not np.count_nonzero(m1) else print('Não Nulo')
Nulo

m2 = m1.copy()
m2[0,0]=1
print('Nulo') if not np.count_nonzero(m2) else print('Não Nulo')
Não Nulo
```

Answer (score 1):

Como `True > False` podemos simplesmente calcular o mínimo recursivamente:

```
def all_0(x):
  if type(x) is list: return min([all_0(y) for y in x])
  else              : return x == 0
```

aplicável a "matrizes" de qualquer tamanho, homogéneas ou heterogéneas (listas generalizadas)

```
print(all_0([[0,[0,0,0],1,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]))           ## False

print(all_0([[0,[0,0,0],0,0],[0,0,0],[0,[[0,0,],0],0]]))  ## True
```